# Evaluating $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \dfrac{1_{[i]\sim [j]}}{N(i)N(j)} $

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, graph-theory

I consider $n$ points distributed uniformly in [0, 1]. I form a graph by connecting two points if the distance is smaller that a certain threshold $r$ . I assume that if two points are mapped to each other then $1_{[i]\sim [j]}= 1 $ otherwise $0$.

Let $N(i)$ be the number of points that are mapped to the point $i$.

My question is how to simplify the following sum:

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \dfrac{1_{[i]\sim [j]}}{N(i)N(j)}  $$

I know that $ \sum\limits_{j=1}^n 1_{[i]\sim [j]} =N(i)$.

I can use this information if I lower bound as:
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \dfrac{1_{[i]\sim [j]}}{N(i)N(j)} > \dfrac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n 1_{[i]\sim [j]}}{N(i)N(j)} =\dfrac{1}{N{j}}$$.

However, I am interested by the equality or an upper bound in the worst case but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Any help is welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: One technical issue: It is possible that a particular point $k$ is isolated - $N(k) = 0$. This probability is small when $n$ is large and $r$ is not too small, but you may need to deal with that anyway. Also I am not exactly sure if I follow your inequality - do you mean you pick the maximum $N(j)$ to replace all denominators so every summand is decreased?

Comment: N(k) is always greater or equal to 1, since 1_{k,k}=1